# ReactNative, What's the benefit of using expo bare workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

There was create-react-native-app just like create-react-app

However I see https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app has been merged to expo.

Since I need native (android or ios) support, I can do either of theses

- expo bare workflow 
  https://docs.expo.io/versions/v34.0.0/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/
- react native init 
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started (react native cli quickstart)

What do I gain by going through expo bare workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Expo, you can use the module in `Expo`. Of course, `Expo` needs to install modules for APK availability starting with `SDK33`. However, you do not need to link the `Expo` separately.

If you use `Expo`, it will automatically reload the code when it is refreshed and not restarted, making it easy to see the code change.

And with fast feedback, the development cycle will be faster. Because the process of communicating from simulator to native apps is still slow, build time will be increased when using Web versions that run directly into the browser, until HMR creates a basic framework for the app because it is fast and fully available with `Chrome Developer tools`.

Also, if you want to install a `React-native` module that requires a link, you can use the '`expo eject`' command to eject `Expo`. Then you can use `React-native`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Probably I should try expo. (although I think the same auto reloading is termed `hot reload` in vanilla react/react-native world?) By ejecting, Can I  integrate native (android activity, ios viewcontroller and so on)  as I want? Is there any major downside or contraint if I go with Expo route?

Comment: @eugene You can use it like React-native if you want to eject Expo. However, it is still possible to see the modification of the code with the eyes.